# Heap big table with performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a business case where I need to store all details about invoices from vehicle workshop (invoice number, dealer,vehicle number, peace, nature of service , ...). I have more than 50 columns which are all selected in the same query.

In my treatment I need to do some specific treatment in order to get cleansed data and some basic transformations. The problem that I'm facing it is that I have no business key to be able to create a primary key because each line of my workshop data represents an invoice details (like a piece reparation) and sometimes I have the same duplicated lines because there are the same operation more than once in the workshop.

So I find myself with a Heap table without any clustered index. So I tried to create some non clustered index to improve performance but it is not really working and every time I load more data the select query takes more times than before.

I checked the execution plan and I observed that the main reason of my problem is RID lookup (Heap) which costs more than 85%

I need some help here ^^ and I already had the idea to create a composite index which define an invoice but it will not be unique in my data set? What do you think?

Comment: A regular b-tree index should be fine.  You should ask another question with an example of a slow query and your current indexing structure.

Comment: Thanks, it's a heap there are not many queries i only run a query to select all data that was loaded in the current day and treat it. So for the moment i have non clustered index in the hope of improving the select query but it doesn't help to much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clustered indexes don't need to be unique (if they're not, SQL adds an internal 'unique-ifier' so rows can be differentiated from each other), so go ahead and create one!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you think with the clustered index there will be any second effects in loading data ? I need to load 1 million lines per day.

Comment: It might be slightly slower than inserting to a heap, but not worryingly so.There's so many variables that affect insert performance that you'll need to test it yourself to be sure. An alternative is to drop the clustered index before the insert & recreate afterwards, again you'll need to test that for speed & any availability requirements.

Comment: @HadriaMehdi, that the best choice for the clustered index key depends much on your queries. There may be some trade-offs involved since a table can have only one clustered index.

Comment: Thanks, I will try my clustered index and see what it gives :). @Dan Guzman, in fact i have only one query to run. It select the recent data from the huge table where it was loaded initially and loading it to a staging table to be treated before loading to a final table.

Comment: @HadriaMehdi please note how long it took you to drop the golden information about what actual query you are running. This has 100% bearing on what indexes you create. It should really be in the original question with a lot more detail.